# existance of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

given $V$ and $W$ vector spaces over a division ring $D$ with $v$ in $V$, $w$ in $W$.Show there exists a linear transformation $f \colon V \to W$ such that $f(v) = w$ ,i tried to do it by defining a map $T\colon V \to W$ by $T(\sum c_i v_i)=\sum c_i T(v_i)$ where $T(v_i)=w_i$ for $1\leq i \leq n$ and $T(v_i)=0$ for $i>n$. Is this true ?

Comment: Your idea is unclear to me (and other readers) since you haven't introduced $v_i$, $w_i$ and the proof doesn't use $v$, $w$ at all.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not correct. For example, it fails if $v=0$ and $w \neq 0$. But this is the only exception. Let $v \neq 0$. Then we can extend (Zorn's Lemma) $\{v\}$ to a basis $B$ of $V$. It is well-known that a linear map $V \to W$ is the "same" as a map $B \to |W|$. So you only have to construct a map $B \to |W|$ which maps $v \mapsto w$, and this is easy.